# Split into 3 character length

Tags: r, split, character

I have very simple question: How can I divide the following text into 3 in a single code

```
mycodes <- c("ATTTGGGCTAATTTTGTTTCTTTCTGGGTCTCTC")
strsplit(mycodes, split = character(3), fixed = T, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

[[1]]
 [1] "A" "T" "T" "T" "G" "G" "G" "C" "T" "A" "A" "T" "T" "T" "T" "G" "T" "T" "T" "C"
[21] "T" "T" "T" "C" "T" "G" "G" "G" "T" "C" "T" "C" "T" "C"
```

This is not what I want; I want three letters at a time:

```
[1] "ATT"  "TGG", "GCT"...............and so on the final may be of one, two or three letters depending upon the letter availability.
```

Thanks;

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want to work with codons.  If that's the case, you might want to look at the Biostrings package from Bioconductor.  It provides a variety of tools for working with biological sequence data.

```
library(Biostrings)
?codons
```

You can achieve what you want, with a little bit of clumsy coercion:

```
as.character(codons(DNAString(mycodes)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using `stringr` package

```
require(stringr)
start = seq(1, nchar(mycodes), 3)
stop  = pmin(start + 2, nchar(mycodes))
str_sub(mycodes, start, stop)
```

Output is

```
[1] "ATT" "TGG" "GCT" "AAT" "TTT" "GTT" "TCT" "TTC" "TGG"
[10] "GTC" "TCT" "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
 strsplit(data, '(?<=.{3})', perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
 [1] "ATT" "TGG" "GCT" "AAT" "TTT" "GTT" "TCT" "TTC" "TGG" "GTC" "TCT" "C"
```

or

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(data, '.{1,3}')
```