# split a string in a text file

Tags: r, bash, awk, split

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
19810101 20
19810102 31
19810103 1
19810701 1
19811105 5
```

I want something like this and save as a csv file.

```
1981 01 01 20
1981 01 02 31
1981 01 03 1
1981 07 01 1
1981 11 05 5
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R, bash or awk?

I was looking at similar posts:
[1] [Split a string every 5 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497583/split-a-string-every-5-characters)
[2][Split into 3 character length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452156/split-into-3-character-length)
but these are all applicable for strings with the same length.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: "Is there an easy way to do this in R, bash or awk?" If that is the question, then the answer is "yes".

Comment: Why not parse the date?

Comment: I think, parsing the date would be an overkill if the date is in such standard format "yyymmdd"... `sed -r 's/(....)(..)(..)/\1 \2 \3/' file` is sufficient

Comment: When you "save as a CSV file", do you expect any commas to be added, or do you keep the spaces?

Comment: Sorry I was out a while ago so I didn't check my post. Before I posted here, I was reading some similar post. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452156/split-into-3-character-length, and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247045/chopping-a-string-into-a-vector-of-fixed-width-character-elements, but I these are all applicable for splitting strings of same length.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat f
19810101 20
19810102 31
19810103 1
19810701 1
19811105 5
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '{print substr($1,1,4),substr($1,5,2),substr($1,7),$2}' f
1981 01 01 20
1981 01 02 31
1981 01 03 1
1981 07 01 1
1981 11 05 5
```

**For CSV**

```
$ awk  '{print substr($1,1,4),substr($1,5,2),substr($1,7),$2}' OFS=, f
1981,01,01,20
1981,01,02,31
1981,01,03,1
1981,07,01,1
1981,11,05,5
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering unless OP clearly shows his research towards solving their problem.

Comment: Wow sorry inian I didn't read fully,   should I delete my answer now ?

Comment: Just trying to maintain the _etics_ of this community. The OP being nearly  3 years in the site should know better to post an effort for this. Refer @anishsane comment above, it already solved the problem, but he hasn't posted it. Waiting for a proper effort shown. So kindly do likewise

Comment: @Inian : Sorry, I will take care of it from my next posts

Answer (score 2):

We can use `extract` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
extract(df1, v1, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), "(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(19810101L, 19810102L, 19810103L, 19810701L, 
 19811105L), v2 = c(20L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

below will work

```
sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})/\1 \2 \3/' lines.txt|tr ' ' , > newfile.csv
```

or

```
sed -r 's/(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})/\1 \2 \3/' lines.txt |tr ' ' ,  > newfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{sub(/..../,"& ")sub(/../,"& ",$2)}1' file

1981 01 01 20
1981 01 02 31
1981 01 03 1
1981 07 01 1
1981 11 05 5
```